# How to select a row with maximum value in a column?

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
table_code        table_family       aa
---------------------------------------
F90                    OT            49 
F93                    OT             1
F92                    OT             1
```

I want to see result as follows:

```
F90              OT                49
```

I have tried the following SQL:

```
SELECT 
    table_code, MAX(table_family) table_family,  aa 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         table_code, table_family, COUNT(*) aa
     FROM
         table1 
     GROUP BY 
         table_code, table_family) 
GROUP BY 
    table_code, AA
```

This did not work.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT TOP(1) table_code, table_family, aa 
FROM table1 
ORDER BY aa DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a single row to be returned, or all rows that contain the max value? Presumably your actual table contains more than three rows?

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE aa = (SELECT MAX(aa) FROM table1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM table1
ORDER BY aa DESC
```

Comment: The order by needs to be DESC

Comment: Thanks @JonathanWillcock You're correct. I realized as soon as I posted my answer. It's already updated. Just saw your post too after I submitted mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE aa = ( SELECT MAX(aa) FROM table );
```